# how to create custom button on table view cell

Tags: iphone, xcode

I want to create custom button in table view.in that by clicking on that button the label will be create with current date.In that button i also have to implement checkbox functionality. I have implemented following code for checkbox functionality:It works fine but i can i create label by checking them YES.Thanks in advance.

```
      UIButton *btnUncheck=[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(260, 35, 20, 20)];

    //btnUncheck=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
     btnUncheck.tag=indexPath.row;
 [btnUncheck setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NO.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[btnUncheck addTarget:self action:@selector(checkBoxClicked:)    forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


  [btnUncheck release];

[cell.contentView addSubview:view];


    return cell;
```

}

```
     -(IBAction)checkBoxClicked:(id)sender
      {


   if(favoriteChecked==NO)
{


    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"YES.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        favoriteChecked=YES;
   [lblAchievementreward setHidden:NO];
        }
else
{


    [sender setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"NO.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    favoriteChecked=NO;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. In `checkBoxClicked:`, save the row of the checked item in an instance variable. Then, reload the row so that cellForRowAtIndexPath is called again. Something like-

```
self.checkedRow = sender.tag;
[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndex:sender.tag]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Then, in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, check for `self.checkedRow` and add a label. Something like-

```
if(indexPath.row == self.checkedRow)
{
       UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
       //label.text = [NSDate date]; //use date formatters here
       [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
}
```